# Why is my viewport glitching in orthographic view and not in perspective view

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view

[Video Link](https://i.imgur.com/JiBy6ka.mp4)

[image]

The Viewport is glitching after I was rapidly switching to and fro between my opera and blender and now I am getting this weird glitch everytime I am trying to model. Pls help.

I am trying to model a ring and this has started to happen. It has never happened to me before so I don't know what's causing it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your <kbd>View</kbd> <kbd>Clip Start</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> values are currently set to fairly extreme values (.001 m and 9999999 m) Right-clicking on each value and choosing <kbd>Reset to Default</kbd> cures the problem here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks John, yes this did it!

Comment: No problem. Make sure they haven't been set that way in your startup file by starting Blender and checking them immediately or you might have the same problem again!