# Degraded image in Viewport Camera View

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have some times a display problem on the viewport.
It only appears in "camera view" and only in "Solid shading" or "Material preview" modes.
The image is totaly degraded (see screenshots).
When I leave the camera view, the image is back to normal.
Anybody an idea of what is going wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help :-).
Jean[image]

Comment: Is your camera far away with long focal length ? If yes, consider using an *Orthographic* camera instead, or reduce the range of *Clip Start* and *Clip End* of your viewport (range should be as small as possible).

Comment: It is possible that the objects in the scene are very small, and in combination with the ortho camera this effect is created.

Comment: I think what only matters is the size and location of objects according to the *Clip* range, regardless of orthographic/perspective. I may be wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my viewport glitching in orthographic view and not in perspective view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308599/why-is-my-viewport-glitching-in-orthographic-view-and-not-in-perspective-view) Also read this article [Depth Buffer Glitches](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/3d_view.html#depth-buffer-glitches) in the Blender manual for more information on this topic.

Comment: @Lutzi Actually the size and location of objects is irrelevant (only in so far that the larger or smaller an object, the more you zoom in or out which also has an effect on the appearance of the artifacts), a much too high range from _Start_ to _End_ can always be problematic and produce artifacts due to depth precision (or lack thereof), and it makes a difference if you use _Orthographic_ or _Perspective_ view. Very low _Start_ values produce mainly artifacts in _Perspective_ view, while very high _End_ values produce artifacts in _Orthographic_ view.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon ! Problem solved ! :-) (It was indeed the clip start and end of my camera :-). Have a good day :-)

Comment: Hi, Jean T, welcome. Since @GordonBrinkmann has solved this one with reference to a similar question, I think it's fair to close this as a duplicate. Nothing personal, just looking after the archive.